# SQL Server python Machine Learning cannot access filesystem

Tags: python, sql-server

SQL Server 2017 using sp_execute_external_script (SQL Server Machine Learning) to run a python script in the context of the database. python script needs to load a file from filesystem. Everything (the database and the filesystem) is local on my PC. Error trace:

Msg 39004, Niveau 16, État 20, Ligne 1

Une erreur de script « Python » s'est produite lors de l'exécution de « sp_execute_external_script » avec HRESULT 0x80004004.

Msg 39019, Niveau 16, État 2, Ligne 1

Une erreur de script externe s'est produite :

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 5, in

File "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\MSSQL1~2.MSS\MSSQL\EXTENS~1\MSSQLSERVER201701\B2E71FC7-8E08-4D86-8B82-38AD564DBC9D\sqlindb.py", line 43, in transform

```
im = Image.open(adresse_image)
```

File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2410, in open

```
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
```

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\aubertl\Downloads\plage_corse_2.jpg'

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.

Message(s) STDOUT provenant du script externe :

Express Edition will continue to be enforced.

SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 406, in rx_sql_satellite_call

```
rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
```

File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER2017\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 291, in rx_native_call

```
ret = px_call(functionname, params)
```

RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default python services run under "NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad". File is located in the "C:\Users\aubertl" folder, which is by default not accessible by MSSQLLaunchpad.
I would advice to create another directory, like C:\PytrhonScripts" and grant read access to this folder to MSSQLLaunchpad.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be the way to go. Can you tell how to grant read access to the folder to MSSQLLaunchpad ? right click on directory -> properties -> security -> Modify -> Add ... there I am trying to add 'NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad$MSSQLSERVER2017', verify name fails.

Comment: Or right click on directory -> grant access to -> specific users -> NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad. verify name fails. Is there a way to find the location of this account ?

Comment: Please try: http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/python-and-r-script-write-to-file-folder-permission-error.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From [Grant all application packages permissions on file folder](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/python-and-r-script-write-to-file-folder-permission-error.aspx):

### Option 1: Interactive

- Launch Windows Explorer and right click on the target file folder.
- From context menu, select `Properties`.
- Switch to `Security` tab.
- Click `Edit` button.
- Click `Add...` to add `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` privileges.
- Tick `Modify` and/or `Full Control` to allow `Read/Write` to this directory.

Can also add `Everyone` to prevent any further issues.

### Option 2: Command line

Adapted from [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611792/sql-server-python-machine-learning-cannot-access-filesystem), run this in an `Administator` command prompt:

```
icacls "X:\DataDir" /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)F" /T
```

Answer (score 0):

right click on directory -> grant access to -> Add "everyone". And then the script runs and produces the desired output. The user the service runs with (NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad) cannot be added apparently, so this is a workaround.

Comment: make sure you are using NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad$ < instance_name >  user otherwise you wont be able to find it in the list of users in AD. Its just a user and you should be able to add it. HTH.